# Creating JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I've followed a tutorial to create a Website Menu, this involves JQuery to provide some transitions.

I've got it working as intended, but to prove I understand this new code and framework, and also, to follow development guidelines, I want to move to the Menu code to a plug-in.

**Working (not-plug-in) version:**
This appears in the .ascx, along with a UL tag, ID = MainMenu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    NavBarMenu();
</script>
```

In another file, NavBar.js, the following code is used to associate some JQuery events:

```
function NavBarMenu() {

    $(function() {
        var $menu = $('#MainMenu');
        var $menu_items = $menu.children('li');
        ...
```

**Not working version:**

Now the plug-in code is created, the NavBarMenu function is called like this from the .ascx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#MainMenu").NavBarMenu();
</script>
```

In NavBar.js I now have:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.NavBarMenu = function() {
        var $menu_items = this.children('li');
```

However, the **$menu_items** variable is unpopulated?

Shouldn't **this** (2nd example) be equivalent to **$('#MainMenu')** (1st example)

I followed this example, where a JQuery selector is switched for the this pointer. http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

There must be other factor affecting my implementation, I will revisit it.

I have created 2 JSFiddle pages, as part of my investigation and it has proved that the JQuery Selector can be swapped for the this pointer in a plug-in.

Fiddle detailing 1st example: http://jsfiddle.net/rL7zpr15/1/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    $( "div" ).css( "background", "green" );
});
```

*Is equivalent to*

Fiddle detailing 2nd example: http://jsfiddle.net/hds7advx/

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "background", "green" );
};

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    $( "div" ).greenify();
});
```